# Cypress cy.click() doesn't work - element is detached from DOM? (React+Cypress)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I'm testing a dropdown in my app with Cypress. The dropdown is a double-dropdown, meaning you first have to select an option in the first part of the dropdown, then the second dropdown opens and then you select the second option. After you do this, the dropdown closes and the app renders the selected option (or all of them if 'Select All' is clicked) as Badges on the DOM

While testing it with cypress, first dropdown works fine, but on the second dropdown it seems that Cypress can't click on the  because the element supposedly "detached from the DOM" I'm wondering why that is? I've already tried cy.wait() and .click({force:true}), nothing works.

The error:
[image]

Cypress console:
[image]

The click goes through, but the state changes don't trigger so the Badges aren't rendering. I will paste the related code below

**Related Cypress test**

```
  cy.url().should('include', url);
  
  cy.get("#tag-selector-dropdown").click();
  cy.get('#tag_type_option_0').invoke('text').then((inputText) => {
      cy.get('#input-tag-type-dropdown').type(inputText);
      cy.get("[id^='tag_type_option_']").then($options => {
          expect($options).to.have.length(1);
          expect($options.first().text()).to.equal(inputText);
      });
      cy.get('#tag_type_option_0').click();
  });
  cy.get('#dropdown-tags').should('be.visible')
  cy.get('#tag_option_1').invoke('text').then((inputText) => {
      cy.get('#input-tag-dropdown').type(inputText);
      cy.get("[id^='tag_option_']").then($options => {
          expect($options).to.have.length(2);
          expect($options.eq(1).text()).to.equal(inputText);
      });  
      cy.get('#input-tag-dropdown').clear();
  });
  cy.get('div#tag_option_all').click(); -this is where cypress can't click

  cy.get("[id^='badge_']").should('be.visible');
```

**Tag Selector (the double dropdown + badge container that shows the selected tags as badges)**

```
      <TagSelectorDropdown
        id="tag-selector-dropdown"
        filterName="Tags"
        allowSelectAll={allowSelectAll}
        allowNewTag={allowNewTag}
        tags={tags}
        marginLeft={marginLeft ?? 20}
        onAdd={handleTagAdd}
        padding={'3px 10px 3px 10px'}
        width={150}
        containerWidth={250}
        font={14}
        lineHeight={22}
        backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
      />
      <TagBadgeContainer tags={tags} onRemoveTag={handleTagRemove} minHeight={minHeight} />
```

**First dropdown**

```
        <SelectDropDown
          id="dropdown-tag-types"
          isVisible={isTagTypeVisible}
          width={width}
          backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
        >
          <Scrollbars hideTracksWhenNotNeeded={true} autoHeightMax={150} autoHeight={true}>
            <div>
              <InputWrapper>
                <StyledFaSearch />
                <Input
                  id="input-tag-type-dropdown"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={'Select Type'}
                  value={tagTypeFilter}
                  onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    setTagTypeFilter(event.target.value);
                  }}
                  width={width}
                  font={font}
                  backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
                  autoFocus
                />
              </InputWrapper>
              {(tagTypesWithTags ?? [])
                .filter((tagType) =>
                  tagType.name.toLowerCase().includes(tagTypeFilter.toLowerCase())
                )
                .map((tagType, i) => (
                  <SelectOption
                    key={tagType.name}
                    checked={false}
                    value={tagType.name}
                    label={tagType.title ?? tagType.name}
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleSelectTagType(tagType);
                    }}
                    id={'tag_type_option_' + i.toString()}
                  />
                ))}
            </div>
          </Scrollbars>
        </SelectDropDown>
```

**Second dropdown**

```
        <SelectDropDown
          id="dropdown-tags"
          isVisible={isTagVisible}
          width={width}
          backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
        >
          <Scrollbars hideTracksWhenNotNeeded={true} autoHeightMax={150} autoHeight={true}>
            <div
              onBlur={(e) => {
                if (
                  document.activeElement === e.currentTarget.querySelector('input[type="text"]')
                ) {
                  return;
                }
                setSelectedTagType(undefined);
                setTagVisible(false);
                setTagFilter('');
              }}
            >
              <InputWrapper>
                <StyledFaSearch />
                <Input
                  id="input-tag-dropdown"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={'Select Tag'}
                  value={tagFilter}
                  onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    setTagFilter(event.target.value);
                  }}
                  width={width}
                  font={font}
                  autoFocus
                />
              </InputWrapper>
              {selectedTagType &&
                allowSelectAll &&
                isAllSelected(selectedTagType) &&
                allTags.some(
                  (tag) =>
                    tag.tagTypeName === selectedTagType?.name &&
                    !tags.some((selectedTag) => selectedTag.name === tag.name)
                ) && (
                  <SelectOption
                    key="all"
                    checked={false}
                    value="all"
                    label="Select All"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleSelectAll();
                    }}
                    id="tag_option_all"
                  />
                )}
              {allTags
                .filter(
                  (tag) =>
                    tag.name.toLowerCase().includes(tagFilter.toLowerCase()) &&
                    tag.tagTypeName === selectedTagType?.name &&
                    !tags.some((selectedTag) => selectedTag.name === tag.name)
                )
                .map((tag, i) => (
                  <SelectOption
                    key={tag.name}
                    checked={false}
                    value={tag.name}
                    label={tag.title ?? tag.name}
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleSelectTag(tag);
                    }}
                    id={'tag_option_' + i.toString()}
                  />
                ))}
              {allTags.filter(
                (tag) =>
                  tag.name.toLowerCase().includes(tagFilter.toLowerCase()) &&
                  tag.tagTypeName === selectedTagType?.name &&
                  !tags.some((selectedTag) => selectedTag.name === tag.name)
              ).length === 0 &&
                allowNewTag && (
                  <SelectOption
                    key="new"
                    checked={false}
                    value="new"
                    isHighlighted={true}
                    label="Add new tag"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setTagModalOpen(true);
                    }}
                    id="option_new"
                  />
                )}
            </div>
          </Scrollbars>
        </SelectDropDown>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the options list is refreshed after the preceding `.clear()` action.

You can try adding re-opening the dropdown,

```js
cy.get('#tag_option_1').invoke('text').then((inputText) => {
  ...
  cy.get('#input-tag-dropdown').clear();
})

cy.get("#tag-selector-dropdown").click()  
cy.get('div#tag_option_all').click()
```

or verify that the list has only one option

```js
cy.get('#tag_option_1').invoke('text').then((inputText) => {
  ...
  cy.get('#input-tag-dropdown').clear();
})

cy.get("[id^='tag_option_']").should('have.length', 1)
cy.get('div#tag_option_all').click()
```

or even add a `wait(0)` in case the hooks are slow to resolve the component

```js
cy.get('#tag_option_1').invoke('text').then((inputText) => {
  ...
  cy.get('#input-tag-dropdown').clear();
})

cy.wait(0)                     // allow hooks to process
cy.get('div#tag_option_all').click()
```